# Regex to get the data from tag from any ID identifier in the tag?

Tags: php, regex

I have used the following regex to get the data between the tag below (Volkswagen Eos) from a page. The page I am working on, it has different id for every item (4222620).

```
preg_match_all('!<span class="p_t"><strong>(.*?)</strong></span>!is', $str2b, $names);
```

the HTML code is below.

```
    <div>
      <span id="clsfd_title_4222620" class="p_t" id=""><strong>Volkswagen Eos</strong></span>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately I can not get the data. Is this because I didn't use the whole tag? If so, what is a regex I can use to get the data of any written ID?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if anyone has suggested this before but have you looked into [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I am aware of DOM, but I built this using regex from the begining and this is the only question to fix the entire problem. Do you think that this can be solved easily with DOM?

Comment: I respect that, I had no intention to offend

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1841533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not mind about id value and id value does not have space or tabs, I think, the regex like this can be used:

```
<span (?:id="\S*" )?class="p_t"(?: id="\S*")><strong>(.*?)</strong></span>
```